# InteroP TyPe "CCoreScannerClass" cannot be Embedded. Use the APPLICABLE INTERFACE INSTED

Tags: c#, winforms, zebra-printers

I've developed a POS using C# and now I'm implementing the Zebra Technologies LS2208 Barcode Scanner according to their documentation but at the beginning, it Prompted me this error "InteroP Type "CCoreScannerClass" cannot be Embedded. Use the APPLICABLE INTERFACE INSTEAD".

According to the documentation, I have started with the console application but still received the same error. Can anyone please guide me?

[image: Here is a Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution which is resolved through the COM library CoreScanner's properties. Set Embedded Interop Type to "False".